# How to process this JSON request swift 4

Tags: json, swift, xcode

This is my Json data  which i need to parse in xcode to display
i want to assign those lat and long into two different variable

```
"latlng":[
28.0,
3.0
],
"capital":"Algiers",
i want to process that latLng into my json
```

My Xcode file , i cannot directly use let latlng:String it gives error at this point as it has two values stored inside it

```
struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String

    //if i put like this it given parsing error and doesn't parse entire data
    let latlng: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your model like :

```
struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String

    let latlng: [Int]
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: You can use whatever you need as array [Int], [Double], [String] at this situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your `latlng` value as an array of `Double` type instead of a `String`.

Update your model like below

```
struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String

    let latlng: [Double]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this way

```
 struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String

    let latlng: [Float]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`latlng` is array of type **Double** not **String**

```
struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String
    let latlng: [Double]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`latlng` is **array**

```
struct jsonData :Decodable {
    let name:String
    let capital:String
    let alpha2Code:String
    let alpha3Code:String
    let region:String
    let subregion:String
    let flag:String

    let latlng: [Double]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using this site: https://app.quicktype.io/ if you don't know how to build structs from your json data ;) it's lazy, fast, powerful and without errors!